# How to tell my asp.net page to use .net 3.5?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

My company recently upgraded from IE 6 to IE 8. My site does not render properly. I wanted to make sure my .net version was fixed before I started to try to fix a problem. I think my web.config file says i'm using 3.5, but if I get an error when running the app I get this:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Why does it say 2.0? rather than 3.5? How do i change this?

(using visual studio 2008, running the site locally)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 all use version 2.0 of the CLR. It is the version of this that you get when you get an ASP.NET error.

Everything is fine.

Comment: Well thats bad news... I was hoping that would fix some of my problems. But thanks!